# A nil class when trying to initialize a deck of cards

Tags: ruby

The following code is resulting in nil and I can't figure out why. Is there something wrong with my initialization?

```
class Card
    VALUES = %w(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A)
    SUITS = %w(S H D C)

    def initialize(suit, value)
        @suit = suit
        @value = value
    end
end

class Deck
    attr_accessor :cards

    def initialize
        @cards = []
        Card::SUITS.each do |suit|
            Card::VALUES.each do |value|
                @cards << Card.new(suit, value)
            end
        end
    end
end

Deck.new

p @cards
```

Comment: Is in the Deck class "initializes" a typo?

Comment: Your `@cards` array is filled with instance variables... not really advisable so I think you need to rethink this one. Maybe try to end up with an array like`@cards` = [[S, 2], [S,3]... etc].

Comment: I want it like that one purpose. I want each card to be a unique object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new object `Deck.new`, but you don't print the value of its `cards` - you print a `@cards` instance variable which in this context is `nil`.

You probably wanted something like `p Deck.new.cards`.

Comment: You are correct. After editing the to_s method in the Card class, it works. Thank you. I'll select your answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`@cards` is not known outside the object. Outside the class `Deck` it is a instance variable of the top-level scope in Ruby.

You have to use the accessor method to get the content:

```
class Card
    VALUES = %w(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A)
    SUITS = %w(S H D C)

    def initialize(suit, value)
        @suit = suit
        @value = value
    end
end

class Deck
    attr_accessor :cards

    def initialize
        @cards = []
        Card::SUITS.each do |suit|
            Card::VALUES.each do |value|
                @cards << Card.new(suit, value)
            end
        end
    end
end

deck = Deck.new  #<--- Store object in a variable

p deck.cards  #<--- Use accessor
```

Answer (score 1):

or just:

```
my_deck = Deck.new

p my_deck.cards
```

Comment: You are correct. I'm sorry but I saw the other answer first.

Answer (score 1):

In short, *instance variables* can only be seen by other methods from within the same class. I believe what you're trying to do is:

```
new_deck = Deck.new
p new_deck.cards
```

Calling the `cards` method on `new_deck` returns `@cards`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your output for `@cards` array is difficult to read and contains object info. I thought I'd offer an alternative I've just conjoured up, hope it helps:

```
class Deck

  attr_writer :suits, :values
  attr_accessor :deck

  def initialize
    suits
    values
    generate_deck
    shuffle
  end

  def generate_deck
    @deck = []
    @suits.each do |suit|
      @values.each { |value| @deck << [suit, value] }
    end
  end

  def suits
    @suits  = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades' ]
  end

  def values
    @values = ('2'..'10').to_a + ['J','Q','K','A']
  end

  #just in case you want to shuffle your deck
  def shuffle
    @deck.shuffle!
  end

end

require 'pp' #this makes the output prettier
new_deck = Deck.new
pp new_deck.deck #calls your current deck so you can see it
```

Output example:

```
$ ruby yourfilename.rb
[["Hearts", "K"],
 ["Spades", "5"],
 ["Clubs", "7"],

 #code omitted... (the rest of your cards would be here)

 ["Clubs", "K"],
 ["Hearts", "5"],
 ["Diamonds", "J"],
 ["Hearts", "7"]]
```

Comment: Yeah I edited the to_s method and it works fine. Thanks for the alternative tho.